# adding two matrices together (using methods, without using numpy)

Tags: python, math, matrix, methods, operators

how can i add a matrix using the implemented methods?

my **problem** is that I don't know very much how I can get an operation to add the matrix correctly.

for example, such an operation:

```
A = 1 2 3       1 2 1
    4 5 6   +   0 1 0
    7 8 9       3 2 1
```

I would like to use the methods from the Matrix class:

```
class Matrix:
    def __init__(self, m, n, init=True):
        if init:
            self.rows = [[0] * n for x in range(m)]
        else:
            self.rows = []
        self.m = m
        self.n = n

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.rows[idx]

    def __setitem__(self, idx, item):
        self.rows[idx] = item

    def __add__(self, mat):
        ret = Matrix(self.m, self.n)

        for x in range(self.m):
            row = [sum(item) for item in zip(self.rows[x], mat[x])]
            ret[x] = row

        return ret
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: @Mureinik I don't know how to properly invoke/initialize the method to make it work properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated to the below runs for me, even though there is room for improvement (checking matrix sizes,...)

```
def getitem(self, idx):
    return self.rows[idx]

def setitem(self, idx, item):
    self.rows[idx] = item

def add(self, mat):
    ret = Matrix(self.m, self.n)

    for x in range(self.m):
        row = [sum(item) for item in zip(self.rows[x], mat.getitem(x))]
        ret.setitem(x,row)
    return ret

mat_a = Matrix(5,5)
mat_b = Matrix(5,5)
mat_b.setitem(slice(0,3),[[1,2,3,4,5],[4,5,6,7,8],[9,10,4,3,1]])
mat_c = mat_a.add(mat_b)
print(mat_c.getitem(slice(0,3)))
```